# No known instance method for selector for my protocol method

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, protocols

this is my protocol.

```
@protocol UCMapviewDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)slideMapviewIn:(id)sender;
- (void)slideMapviewOut:(id)sender;


@end
```

This is were the methods should get called (In UCMapViewController.m). showMenu gets called from a button

```
- (void)showMenu
{
    // TODO: 
    if (self.isMapViewPushedAside) {
        [self.delegate slideMapviewOut:self];
    } [self.delegate slideMapviewIn:self];

}
```

And this is were the delegate is initialized. initializer for a UCMapViewController object.

```
- (id)initWithDelegate:(UCRootViewController *)controller
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.delegate = controller;
    }
    return self;
}
```

but when I want to use the delegate to call it, I get the error: `No known instance method for selector 'slideMapviewIn:'`. what can I do about this?

Comment: Show how you are creating that object and calling the method on the object.

Comment: Is `delegate` of type `id<UCMapviewDelegate>`?

Comment: it's id.. when I try to declare it id<UCMapviewDelegate>, it says "Use of undeclared identifier 'UCMapViewDelegate'. so declare it id<UCMapviewDelegate>, i must import the protocol.h, but you only import this into the files that implement that protocol

Comment: @MJB: you don't need to import the header. only need to forward declare it with `@protocol UCMapviewDelegate;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not declaring your delegate as implementing that protocol.  If you don't do that, how is it supposed to know that it implements that protocol?  That error is natural.

You must declare it as `id<UCMapviewDelegate>` and to do that you must import the header that contains that protocol.

Comment: but I thought you must only import the header to the file that implements the protocol?

Comment: Nope, every file the has an object that implements the protocol needs it so it knows how to deal with it.  It's the same as importing a class header to use the class functions.  If you use a protocol (even just assigning it to an object) you must import its header.

Comment: No, they do not need to make it `id<UCMapviewDelegate>`. `id` works fine. It does not need "to know that it implements that protocol". You can send any message to any object in Objective-C (and `id` will make it not do static checks) as long as it is declared anywhere. I believe the issue is related to ARC.